# Qml upload a file (path)

Tags: javascript, upload, qml

I have a pure qml app and I want to upload a file (image) with xmlhttprequest with the javascript implementation of qml. I have a file picker, where I got the path as a string, but how can I now upload the file correctly?

```
function upload ( path, callback ) {

        // Send the file to the server
        var requestUrl = "https://matrix.org/_matrix/media/r0/upload"
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open( "POST", requestUrl, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
                callback ( JSON.parse(http.responseText) )
            }
        }

        // This does not work :-(
        http.send ( path )
}
```

Comment: what is `path` here?

Comment: I have a file picker, where I got the path as a string

Comment: I guess it's impossible to send file in pure QML. Due to security limitation QML has no direct access to a file system. Also `XMLHttpRequest` subsystem doesn't support `FormData`. I'm afraid the only way to do that is to use C++ extension.

Answer (score -3):

Look at this for your help (mozilla) :

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Use this to check if You send any data in server side (PHP) (Mozilla  Example)

<?php
/* register.php */
header("Content-type: text/plain");
/*
NOTE: You should never use `print_r()` in production scripts, or
otherwise output client-submitted data without sanitizing it first.
Failing to sanitize can lead to cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.
*/
echo ":: data received via GET ::\n\n";
print_r($_GET);
echo "\n\n:: Data received via POST ::\n\n";
print_r($_POST);
echo "\n\n:: Data received as \"raw\" (text/plain encoding) ::\n\n";
if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) { echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA; }
echo "\n\n:: Files received ::\n\n";
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

This is information based in PHP to clarify the answer procedure, only example this not's Qml code of course!!

Comment: QML is different to PHP

Comment: qml is javascript I know, I say how can you check your script, if you need to check what you send me I can provide php on one of our servers for your specific tests of this case. You can also implement the response in nodejs to check your problem.

Comment: You need server process to retrieve the image in the server or destination, either php nodejs ... are you the destination service?

Comment: sorry my englsh in spanish better.

Comment: It seems to me that you do not understand the question. The asker has desktop application written in QML that you want to send a file to an external server, it is understood that the server part does not depend on it. He wants to write a client that connects to the server and sends the files to the server.

Comment: your process is client - server you send but if not any process in destination (server) not running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172852/discussion-between-angel-fructuoso-and-eyllanesc).